# Is jQuery a monad

Tags: jquery, functional-programming, monads

I read somewhere that jQuery is a monad and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431999/does-the-chain-function-in-underscore-js-create-a-monad) shows that chain function in underscore.js library is not a monad (but comonad). And [answer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058124/is-this-a-monad) which is similar, shows that is monoid.

So, is jQuery a monad?

Comment: I don't know jQuery, so have limited ability to answer this but things [having co-monadic structure generally implies also having monadic structure][1] if you look at them the right way

  [1]: http://comonad.com/reader/2011/monads-from-comonads/

Comment: Are you asking someone to show that the monad laws hold for the core of the jQuery API?

Comment: "Monad" really describes a method (and a pattern of use) rather than a type. jQuery have a large number of methods, but none of them (AFAICT) conforms to the definition of monad. And that is a good thing! jQuery would just be more verbose and cumbersome if it was based on monadic chaining.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Most APIs do not satisify the monad laws. `jQuery` is a large `API`, so statistically, it is unlikely to be "accidentally" monadic. As a result I am pretty skeptical that the `jQuery` API as a whole could satisfy the monad laws (i.e. that "jQuery is a monad").

This doesn't mean that a given (very restricted) subset might not satisfy them, but the API as a whole is likely to contain "unsafe" operations that would violate the laws when used, breaking the abstraction.

Since no one seems to have offered evidence that the API in whole or part satisifies the laws, I suggest we should assume it does not, until evidence is provided.

It must be shown:

- what jQuery operation corresponds to `return` (lifting a value into the jQuery monad)?
- what jQuery operation corresponds to `bind`, for gluing computations together?
- how do the left-, right- and associativity laws hold over those operations?

And then, what law violations are possible given the rest of the jQuery API? Can I, for example, break the `bind` by calling one of the other API functions?

References:

- [jQuery is not a monad](http://coder.cl/2011/12/jquery-is-not-a-monad/)
- [jQuery still is not a monad](http://www.quora.com/Is-jQuery-a-monad)

Answer (score 12):

I think you're referring to jQuery's implicit looping behavior. In that respect jQuery is similar to working in the list monad, where chaining is equivalent to `bind`, and wrapping an element in `$()` is akin to `return` (I guess).

So where with jquery you might append a new list element to a bunch of divs of lists with:

```
$('div').children().append("<li>New list element</li>");
```

...in haskell you might have:

```
appendToEachList divs = divs >>= children >>= append "<li>New list element</li>"
```

The above is from memory and should be considered pseudocode nonsense.

Anyway, I think it would be a stretch to say "jQuery is a Monad".