# Monad pattern on receiver

Tags: javascript, monads, livescript

As I learn about monads after reading dozens of tutorials I'm trying to implement the pattern in JavaScript. I'm using [LiveScript](http://livescript.net/) and [Prelude](http://preludels.com/) to translate some Haskell monad examples.

So the monad I'm trying to implement as an exercise is the List monad. I wrote the following, in LiveScript:

```
List = do ->
  # unit :: a -> ma
  unit = (a) -> [a]
  # bind :: ma -> (a -> mb) -> mb
  bind = (ma, f) --> concat (map f) ma
  # lift :: (a -> b) -> ma -> mb
  lift = (f, ma) --> bind ma, (a) -> unit f a

  {unit, bind, lift}

add1 = (x) -> x+1

let {unit, bind} = List
  x <- bind [1]
  y <- bind [2]
  z <- bind [3]
  unit add1 x+y+z #=> [7]

(List.lift add1) [1 2 3] #=> [2 3 4]
```

The LiveScript syntax to nest functions at the same level of indentation is quite handy, but it translates to a JavaScript callback hell obviously:

```
List = function(){
  var unit, bind, lift;
  unit = function(a){
    return [a];
  };
  bind = curry$(function(ma, f){
    return concat(map(f)(ma));
  });
  lift = curry$(function(f, ma){
    return bind(ma, function(a){
      return unit(f(a));
    });
  });
  return { unit: unit, bind: bind, lift: lift };
}();
add1 = function(x){
  return x + 1;
};
(function(arg$){
  var unit, bind;
  unit = arg$.unit, bind = arg$.bind;
  bind([1], function(x){
    return bind([2], function(y){
      return bind([3], function(z){
        return unit(add1(x + y + z));
      });
    });
  });
}.call(this, List));
List.lift(add1)([1, 2, 3]);
```

What I want is to implement the pattern on the receiver to be able to use it like so:

```
List([1]).bind([2]).bind([3]).do(function(x,y,z){ x+y+z });
```

After watching [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkZFtimgAcM) where Crockford explains monads in JavaScript ([code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/monad)), I understand that the `MONAD` he presents is just an object with methods that could be also be implemented with prototypes. The `unit` method is the constructor and `bind` is an instance method that runs a function on the value with the given arguments. Then `lift` adds a new method to the prototype that runs the given function on the monadic value.

But, is it an actual monad or a monadic pattern [like jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496932/is-jquery-a-monad)? I have doubts about this particular explanation of monads because there is no computation sequence, the `bind` method runs the function right away and returns a new instance of the "monad", it is not composition, as in the monad I implemented in LiveScript which was based on the Haskell examples.

So my question is:

1. Is my implementation of monad correct?
2. Is [Crockford's implementation](https://github.com/douglascrockford/monad) of monad correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what `List([1]).bind([2]).bind([3]).do(function(x,y,z){ x+y+z });` is supposed to do. `bind` does usually take a function (which produces a list)?

Comment: I think that's the part I don't quite understand yet, is how to make the monad work on the receiver but still use function composition. How would it have to look like with my example then?

Comment: You have three monad instances there so it won't be easy. Those LiveScript backcalls, just as Haskells do-notation, is just syntactical sugar for the *necessary* `lift` callback hell. You still will need to write `List([1]).bind((x)->List([2]).bind((y)->List([3]).bind((z)->List.unit(x+y+z))))`. Surely you could implement some sugar function for that, in this case [`lift3`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM3).

Comment: I was trying to gather the values and make a dynamic binding function then in the `do` method I would `foldl (<<) fns` to compose them, but didn't work. I see what you mean, you have to pass the functions anyway. I understand that with the single `lift` function I can simply do `unit 1 |> lift add 2 |> lift add 3 |> lift add1 #=> [7]`, in LiveScript, but it would still look like a mess in JS. So I understand that functions must be of one argument and I must create many `liftX` depending on how many instances I have?

Comment: Yeah, if expressed in terms of `lift` it will always be a "mess" in JS. To make it better (and more performant), you'd use a comprehension: `concat(for x in [1] for y in [2] for z in [3]: x+y+z)`. Another idea: due to JavaScript's lax typing it should be possible to implement a true generic (recursive?) `liftN` function with variadic arguments if you want.

Comment: Yeah, comprehension for list monad will do. I actually tried implementing other monads with comprehensions but it looked like a mess in LiveScript too. _"true generic recursive lift"_ -- This sounds exactly like what I want. I will ditch Crockfords implementation, and give it a try. This will keep me busy (until my next question...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is my implementation of monad correct?

Yes, your `unit` and `bind` functions do what is expected from the List monad.

However, the second line, `List([1]).bind([2]).bind([3]).do(function(x,y,z){ x+y+z });` does not look like a monad at all.

Those LiveScript backcalls, just as Haskell's do-notation, is just syntactical sugar for the necessary `lift` callback hell. You still will need to write:

```
List([1]).bind((x)->List([2]).bind((y)->List([3]).bind((z)->List.unit(x+y+z))))‌
```

If expressed in terms of `bind` it will always be a "mess". To make it better (and more performant), you'd use a list comprehension:

```
concat(for x in [1] for y in [2] for z in [3]: x+y+z)
```

Another idea: due to JavaScript's lax typing it should be possible to implement a true generic (recursive?) `liftN` function with variadic arguments if you want:

```
function lift(n, fn) {
    var argsPos = 2;
    if (typeof n != "number") {
        fn = n;
        n = fn.length;
        argsPos--;
    }
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, argsPos);
    if (n < args.length) // curry
        return function(){
            return lift.apply(null, [n, fn].concat(args, [].slice.call(arguments)));
        }
    return (function bindr(bound, args)
         if (!args.length)
             return unit(fn.apply(null, bound));
         return bind(args[0], function(a) {
             return bindr([x].concat(bound), args.slice(1));
         });
    })([], args);
}
```

If you want to use a more object-orientated pattern, then you could map the single combinations to argument tuples which you can apply in the end:

```
List([1]).nest(List([2])).nest(List([3])).do(function(x,y,z){ x+y+z })
// where
Monad.prototype.map = function(fn) {
    var unit = this.constructor; // ???
    return this.bind(function(x)
        return unit(fn(x));
    });
};
Monad.prototype.nest = function(m2) {
    return this.map(function(x) {
        return m2.map(function(y)
            return [x, y]; // tuple
        });
    });
});
Monad.prototype.do = function(fn, n) {
    function flatten(n, t) {
        return n<=1 ? [t] : flatten(n-1, t[0]).concat([t[1]]);
    }
    return this.map(function(ts) {
        return fn.apply(null, flatten(n || fn.length, ts));
    });
};
```

> Is Crockford's implementation of monad correct?

Maybe. He does implement the idendity monad, but the code looks as if he wants to extend it to other monads by overwriting the `bind` method, which might not work easily for all monads.