# What Category theory object makes Array in JavaScript chainable?

Tags: javascript, category-theory

I don't know much about Category theory but I bet array chaining has a name in category theory. Is it monoid? I was [asking a long time ago about a proof of concept library that I've written and someone said that it's monoid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5058124/387194).

I'm talking about code like this:

```js
const result = [1,2,3,4].map(x => x * 2)
                        .filter(x => x % 2 == 0)
                        .filter(x => x > 4)
```

Each method returns a new object of the same type that is modified.

but you can also use a method that returns different types like single values (`Array::find` `Array::reduce`).

What objects in Category theory have the same behavior/rules?

Would it be a Monad if there were only methods that return the new Array?

I wanted to ask on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), but it lacks a Category Theory tag.

Comment: You've got it the wrong way round. There is no "type theory object that makes something chainable". Rather, arrays are chainable in a way that makes them (or rather: that particular chaining operation on arrays) behave like a certain type theory object. So which operation are you asking about? You've mentioned like five different ones in your question.

Comment: Methods are *chainable* if they return an object of the same type as one of their inputs. That has nothing to do with category theory.

Comment: Questions like this are probably more appropriate for [cs.se] or [langdev.se]

Comment: @Bergi I know that chainability is only side effect caused by the language, but here is there is an object that has methods that returns object of same type. The same as with jQuery. So if you can ask [if jQuery is a monad](https://www.google.com/search?hl=pl&q=jQuery%20is%20a%20monad) or something similar why you can't ask the same thing about Array?

Comment: Because you'd get [the same elusive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10499668/1048572). The Array API is vast, and some subsets of it may or may not form a monad - it's on you to be more specific. And again, method chainability has nothing to do with it.